# SignalR: amount of async server-methods calls limited to 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, signalr, async-await

I'm started playing with SignalR and faced with that behaviour - 
marking public method in hub with async limits number of simultaneous client calls to 5. Once any of running operations finished, next call from some queue (or buffer) reaches the method in hub (at least stops at breakpoint)

```
public async Task<string> RunNewOperation()
{
    var operation = await _operationContainer.RunNewOperation("Custom task", TaskDummy.DummyAction);

    return "task result";
}
```

Removing `async` from hub method makes it possible to run any amount of tasks

```
public string RunNewOperation()
{
    var operation = _operationContainer.RunNewOperation("Custom task", TaskDummy.DummyAction);

    return "task result";
}
```

So the question is - is that a proper behaviour? and if yes, how to avoid such troubles and allow user to make any amount of async method calls?

Here is the code sample https://github.com/jsdmc/Asp.Net-MVC-SignalR-tasks-container-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting the [connection limit per hostname](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network) which is enforced by the browser.

Your best option is not to wait for the return value but instead have the server make an active call to provide the value to the client once the operation is complete.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! Tested in IE11 - limit is 13. But I don't get what is the difference on the client without using "async" (why no limits in that case)?

Comment: Without async, the hub method can return immediately and signalr can send its response without waiting for anything. Once the long polling request is complete, the client can send a new request, so if the server waits, the client's connection is still open and counts against the limit.